# Split a json and show it with ng-repeat angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, parsing, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can I see a list of `Key: value` of a split json string?

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    var jsonString='{"prop":"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6", "prop": "lol, asd, lidfj", "prop": "asd, test!!!"}';
    $scope.evalled=$scope.$eval(jsonString);
    
    $scope.fromJsoned=angular.fromJson(jsonString);
    
  $scope.ljson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">     
        <p>JSON.parse:</p>
        <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="son in ljson">Key: {{son.key }}, Value: {{son}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The target is, in this example, display:

```
 - Key: prop, Value: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
 - Key: prop, Value: lol, asd, lidfj
 - Key: prop, Value: asd, test!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-repeat="(key, value) in data"`. Then your code becomes

```
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in ljson">Key: {{key }}, Value: {{value}}</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json string is not an array, which ng-repeat needs to do it's repeating.

You want this:

```
var jsonString='[{"prop":"1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6"}, {"prop": "lol, asd, lidfj"}, {"prop": "asd, test!!!"}]';
```

Answer (score 0):

The script:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

var result = []
for (var key in obj){
    result.push({key:key, value: obj[key]});
}

$scope.ljson = result;
```

The html:

```
<li ng-repeat="son in ljson">Key: {{son.key }}, Value: {{son.value}}</li>
```

Not sure it will handle the multiple "prop" well though